# Python - Can't seem to get return statement to work in simple function?

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement, return

I have a simple function accessing a dictionary with an if statement.

```
 langdict = {"english": "Hello, World!", "french":"Bonjour, tout le monde!"}

 def hello(language):
     if language in langdict:
         return langdict[language]
     else:
         return None
```

Now everything works fine and dandy with print statements obviously. But nothing happens when I use the return statement on both lines 5 and 7. What am I missing?

Comment: nothing happens? you mean _nothing is printed_ right?

Comment: BTW replace that by `return langdict.get(language)`. It returns `None` if not found no need for all that

Comment: Yeah the first return statement is not printing anything for some reason.

Comment: `return` does not print anything, `print` prints to the screen. So to see the output you would want to make a statement outside the function along the lines of `hello("english")` or `hello("french")`. In short, `return` only returns a value to where the function was called (here it was never called), while `print` prints it to screen.

Comment: @user2951723 it prints only within the interactive interpreter.

Comment: Okay yeah Im wording thing wrong. I just meant that its not giving any output like it should. Or wasn't at least. I switched my editor and it worked just fine in a different editor. So my previous editor must have been bugged or something...idk?

Answer (score 0):

You may use this one

```
 def hello(language):
     return langdict.get(language, None)

print hello('english')  #Hello, World!
print hello('japanese')  #None
```

return will return that value from function and print will display that value in console

Comment: This is not answering the question whatsoever. This is just changing the code to make it a bit more presentable and concise, but not finding a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am using python 2.7 and couldn't reproduce your error:

By calling

```
hello("english")
```

I get the expected result `'Hello, World!'` while calling for example

```
 hello("german")
```

results in no/ empty result

If you want to store the result into a variable you would do something like:

```
result =  hello("english")
```